# Replace single spaces in vim includeexpr

Tags: vim

I want to be able to visually select words separated by spaces, type `gf` and skip to the file name with the spaces replaced by underscores while respecting `suffixesadd`.

For example, I could visually select 'vim shortcuts', type `gf` and jump to 'vim-shortcuts.md'.  '.md' is included in my `suffixesadd` setting.

I've tried this setting:

```
:set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\s','_','g')
```

I'm not sure if this is the intended usage of `includeexpr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me with `'\ '` instead of `'\s'`:

```
:set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'\ ','_','g')
```

Comment: I feel foolish for not testing that.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem. But don't be too harsh with yourself. As we say: The darkest place is under the candlestick.